# Filtering two models

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with following thing: using models described below, I need to search for a car, that has more than x km of mileage and latest visit has date of more than year ago. Of course one car can have more than one visit.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    mileage = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)


class Visit(models.Model):
    ...
    id = models.ForeignKey(Car, db_column='id', db_index=False)
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
```

In views.py I have code like this

```
def search_car(request):
    time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365)
    cars = Car.objects.filter(mileage__gte=500000,
    id=Visit.objects.filter(data__lt=time_threshold.date()))

  return render(request, 'myapp/search_car.html', {'cars': cars})
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

**EDIT** Exact code:
models.py

```
class Samochod(models.Model):
marka = models.CharField(max_length=30)
model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
nr_rejestracyjny = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
nr_VIN = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True, validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(17)])
przebieg = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
id_uzytkownika = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='id_uzytkownika', db_index=True)


class Wizyta(models.Model):
id_wizyty = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)
data = models.DateField(db_index=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=STAN_CHOICE, db_index=True)
id_uzytkownika = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='id_uzytkownika', db_index=True)
nr_rejestracyjny = models.ForeignKey(Samochod, db_column='nr_rejestracyjny', db_index=False)
przebieg_w_momencie_wizyty = models.PositiveIntegerField()
opis = models.CharField(max_length=200)
id_czesci = models.ForeignKey(Czesci, db_column='id_czesci')
cena = models.PositiveIntegerField()
czas_pracownikow = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[validators.MaxValueValidator(1000)])
id_sprzetu = models.ForeignKey(Sprzet, db_column='id_sprzetu', db_index=True)
```

views.py

```
def search_car(request):
    time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365)
    samochody = Samochod.objects.distinct().filter(przebieg__gte=500000).exclude(wizyta__date__gte=time_threshold)

    return render(request, 'warsztat_app/search_car.html', {'samochody': samochody})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cars = Car.objects.distinct().filter(mileage__gte=500000) \
                             .exclude(visit__date__gte=time_threshold)
```

For your real models code should look like this:

```
samochody = Samochod.objects.distinct().filter(przebieg__gte=500000) \
                                       .exclude(wizyta__data__gte=time_threshold)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is an error "Relation fields do not support nested lookups."

Comment: Which version of django do you use?

Comment: My django version is 1.7.1

Comment: I checked this code with django 1.7.1 and it works fine with your models.  Show the exact code which you try to run, please.

Comment: Date field in your `Wizyta` model is called "data" (not "date").  So lookup should be `exclude(wizyta__data__gte=time_threshold)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still incorrect. There is no error, but 'samochody' is empty even if time treshold is set to 0 and przebieg (mileage) is set to 1, which should give me cars which last visit was even yesterday and has mileage above 1. And I'm 100% sure that cars like this exists in my database.

Comment: Here is the SQL for that filter: `SELECT DISTINCT "app_samochod"."id", "app_samochod"."model", "app_samochod"."przebieg" FROM "app_samochod" WHERE ("app_samochod"."przebieg" >= 500000 AND NOT ("app_samochod"."id" IN (SELECT U1."nr_rejestracyjny" AS "nr_rejestracyjny" FROM "app_wizyta" U1 WHERE U1."data" >= 2014-01-14)))`. It is correct. Something wrong with your data.

Comment: It took me some time to test SQL statement you provided and your answer, and it seems that it's working! Thank you very much!